# Bitmap colors change while scrolling

Tags: android

I have a ListView that has a subtle gradient bitmap in the background of each item.  I noticed that when I scroll the list, the background gradient becomes banded and changes color.  The gradient is a dark gray and when it scrolls is becomes subtly green and banded.  It basically looks like the quality of the images greatly decreases as it scrolls.

Most of the time, as soon as it finishes scrolling, it returns to the normal quality.  Sometimes it actually stays poor quality even after scrolling stops.  On a Nexus One it almost always stays low quality after scrolling.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Note:  This is not the common ListView background problem discussed here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Here is an enlarged screen cap to show the difference.  On the left side is the background normally.  On the right half you can see what it looks like when it scrolls.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `android:cacheColorHint="#0000"` to your ListView in xml.

Comment: I had it at #00000000.  I tried your suggestion of #0000 but that didn't make any difference.  Then I tried #000000 and now it's working perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Interesting that that worked for you. Your original 8-digits of zero should be the correct setting. Whatever works, I guess! O_o

Comment: @kcoppock I have this problem too, and setting cacheColorHint to #000000 solves it, but I also have a custom list background too, and it now turns black when scrolling. Do you know any way to solve both problems?